# How can create records using input date and save the param using ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to generate records according when somebody choose a date it will save more records according an input value.

Controller

```
##./app/controller/user_job_controller.rb
def new
  @user_job = UserJob.new
end

def user_job_params
  params.require(:user_job).permit!
end
```

Model

```
#user_job.rb
after_save :save_default_values, :if => :new_record?

private
  def save_default_values

    if params[:dateadd].to_i > 0
      params[:dateadd].to_i.times do |i|
         self.name = params[:name]      
         self.dateuser = params[:dateuser] + i+ 1.day
      end
    else
      self.name = params[:name]
      self.dateuser = params[:dateuser]          
    end
    
  end
```

View

```
<%= form_with(model: user_job) do |form| %>
   Name:<%= form.text_field :name %>
   Date: <%= text_field_tag "dateuser", params[:dateuser].to_i %>
   Date added: <%= text_field_tag "dateadd", params[:dateadd].to_i %>
   <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Example with data:

```
 #form values
 Name: test
 Date: 23-09-2021
 days added: 2
```

Result Wanted:

```
 #it will do on console or ruby on rails logs
  insert into user_jobs (id:1, name:test, dateuser: 23-09-2021),
  insert into user_jobs (id:2, name:test, dateuser: 24-09-2021),
  insert into user_jobs (id:3, name:test, dateuser: 25-09-2021),
```

The log is showing that is not

```
Processing by UserJobsController#create as HTML
 Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user_job"=>{"name"=>"test"}, "dateuser"=>"2021-09-24", "dateadd"=>"2", "commit"=>"Create User job"}
 Unpermitted parameter: :name
```

Result log:

```
  insert into user_jobs(created_at: 23-09-2021)
```

Can you please help me to save the data correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in the codes.

#### 1. params are only accessible in controller, you wanted to read it in your model

There are many ways to pass params value to model, for example, you can add `attr_accessor :dateadd` to the model.
But I think a clearer way is to extract the behavior in :save_default_values into a *new public method* and call it in the controller.

#### 2. params[:name] is an attribute in the model, you should use strong parameters to assign the attributes

#### 3. it's apparently that dateuser is a column of user_jobs, isn't it?

We can use `date_field` to pick the date and also add this field into strong parameter.

#### 4. After a record saved, that record is not new record any more since it has id value.

Try to use `after_create` or `after_save on: :create`. However, I don't use this callback in the code below, but it's just personal choice :)

```rb
# user_job.rb
class UserJob < ApplicationModel
  # add new public method
  def add_additional_jobs!(days)
    (1..days).each do |n|
      UserJob.create!(name: name, dateuser: dateuser + n.days)
    end
  end
end

# user_jobs_controller.rb
class UserJobsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user_job = UserJob.new
  end

  def create
    UserJob.transaction do
      @user_job = UserJob.create!(user_job_params)
      if params[:dateadd].to_i > 0
        @user_job.add_additional_jobs!(params[:dateadd].to_i)
      end
    end
  end
  
  private

  def user_job_params
    params.require(:user_job).permit(:name, :dateuser)
  end
end
```

Then in the view

```
<%= form_with(model: user_job) do |form| %>
  Name:<%= form.text_field :name %>
  Date: <%= form.date_field :dateuser %>
  Date added: <%= text_field_tag "dateadd", params[:dateadd].to_i %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi @kevinluo201 i used the code and is saving the information but its not saving the date from the textbox, can you please check the result wanted on the top? for example Name: test  | Date: 23-09-2021 | days added: 2  this should save 3 records (23-09-2021, 24-09-2021, 25-09-2021)

Comment: @EzioAuditore It should be a date picker field rather than a textbox. I used `form.date_field :dateuser`. Does it help you?